# Why does my Slackware 13.37 freeze with a kernel bug?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, slackware

My Slackware 13.37 started to freeze from time to time. Mouse and keyboard stops working, while xmms still playing the song. I paste my syslog and I hope someone could see the reason it crashes.

```
BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffc90004ae0000
IP: [<ffffffffa04b1dc0>] render_ring_add_request+0x4c0/0x500 [i915]
PGD 14f80d067 PUD 14f80e067 PMD 148e2c067 PTE 0
Oops: 0002 [#1] SMP 
last sysfs file: /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full
CPU 2 
Modules linked in: snd_seq_dummy snd_seq_oss snd_seq_midi_event snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_pcm_oss snd_mixer_oss ipv6 cpufreq_ondemand acpi_cpufreq freq_table mperf lp ppdev parport_pc parport fuse i915 nouveau snd_hda_codec_hdmi iwlagn ttm mac80211 drm_kms_helper compat snd_hda_codec_realtek cfg80211 drm rfkill r8169 intel_agp i2c_algo_bit snd_hda_intel mii evdev processor thermal shpchp uvcvideo video intel_gtt snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep sg videodev v4l1_compat v4l2_compat_ioctl32 thermal_sys snd_pcm snd_timer snd i2c_i801 agpgart i2c_core psmouse serio_raw sparse_keymap rtc_cmos output rtc_core usbhid hid wmi soundcore rtc_lib battery button ac hwmon snd_page_alloc

Pid: 4282, comm: X Not tainted 2.6.37.6 #3 ASUSTeK Computer Inc. N53SV/N53SV
RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffa04b1dc0>]  [<ffffffffa04b1dc0>] render_ring_add_request+0x4c0/0x500 [i915]
RSP: 0018:ffff880145051b88  EFLAGS: 00010202
RAX: ffff8801465f0000 RBX: ffff88014a746800 RCX: 0000000000020000
RDX: 0000000001fff004 RSI: ffffc90004ac0000 RDI: ffff88014f96c000
RBP: ffff880145051bb8 R08: ffff880145050000 R09: 0000000000000001
R10: 0000000000001946 R11: 00000000ffffffff R12: 0000000000169367
R13: ffff8801465f0000 R14: ffff8801293ae800 R15: ffff8801465f0000
FS:  00007f1af94a58a0(0000) GS:ffff88001fc40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
CR2: ffffc90004ae0000 CR3: 0000000133310000 CR4: 00000000000406e0
DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Process X (pid: 4282, threadinfo ffff880145050000, task ffff880100106d00)
Stack:
 ffff8801465f0030 ffff8801465f0030 ffff8800aab83a40 ffff88014a746800
 ffff8801293ae800 ffff8801465f0000 ffff880145051c18 ffffffffa0485604
 ffff880145051c18 ffffffffa04b1edf 0fbfc2440fbfc000 ffff88006ccd8600
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffffa0485604>] i915_add_request+0x54/0x1f0 [i915]
 [<ffffffffa04b1edf>] ? render_ring_flush+0xdf/0x150 [i915]
 [<ffffffffa0489707>] i915_gem_do_execbuffer.clone.38+0xda7/0x1140 [i915]
 [<ffffffffa0489b68>] i915_gem_execbuffer2+0xc8/0x220 [i915]
 [<ffffffffa00ea514>] drm_ioctl+0x3e4/0x4c0 [drm]
 [<ffffffffa0489aa0>] ? i915_gem_execbuffer2+0x0/0x220 [i915]
 [<ffffffff8113002d>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x9d/0x580
 [<ffffffff81130591>] sys_ioctl+0x81/0xa0
 [<ffffffff81002a2b>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
Code: 00 8b 50 68 48 8b 48 48 c7 04 11 00 59 00 00 83 40 68 04 48 8b 83 50 03 00 00 41 8b 95 e4 03 00 00 8b 48 68 83 ca 04 48 8b 70 48 <89> 14 0e 83 40 68 04 48 8b 83 50 03 00 00 8b 50 68 48 8b 48 48 
RIP  [<ffffffffa04b1dc0>] render_ring_add_request+0x4c0/0x500 [i915]
 RSP <ffff880145051b88>
CR2: ffffc90004ae0000
```

Answer (score 0):

i915 is your Graphics driver, try downgrading or upgrading it for several versions. If that doesn't resolve the issue try again with the latest version and file a bug with that version.